# Coordorder в YMapsML

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Собственно вопрос: в YMapsML есть GML полигоны с posList внутри в качестве самой географии. Но карта эти координаты парсит в порядке latlong, без учета параметра инициализации "...&coordorder=longlat...". Есть ли какой-то способ переключить обработку YMapsML на другой порядок координат? Ну или хотя бы какой-нибудь готовый XSLT для конвертации?

Comment: Вы сами создали этот файл или получили его где-то?

Comment: @se0ga сконвертировал из того GML, что отдает SQL Server. Пойду писать страшный XSLT, который поменяет местами точки в posList :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете YMapsML то координаты должны быть указаны в «долгота, широта» https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/ymapsml/1.x/guide/concepts/geodata-docpage/